# How to check whether the file path is a hard link and preserve it while copying to other directory in c++

Tags: c++, file, filesystems, rsync, hardlink

I am using below code to create hard link and identify whether the file is having hard link count of 2.

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
 
int main()
{
    // On a POSIX-style filesystem, each directory has at least 2 hard links:
    // itself and the special member pathname "."
    fs::path p = fs::current_path();
    std::cout << "Number of hard links for current path is "
              << fs::hard_link_count(p) << '\n';
 
    // Each ".." is a hard link to the parent directory, so the total number
    // of hard links for any directory is 2 plus number of direct subdirectories
    p = fs::current_path() / ".."; // Each dot-dot is a hard link to parent
    std::cout << "Number of hard links for .. is "
              << fs::hard_link_count(p) << '\n';
}
```

This is what i have done below for symlink:

```
 else if (fs::is_symlink(srcFilePath)){
        std::cout<<srcFilePath;
        std::filesystem::path p(srcFilePath);
            cpSoftLink(srcFilePath, dstFilePath);

    }

void cpSoftLink(const fs::path & srcPath, const fs::path & dstpath){
// if symbolic link already exists then don't create it again
    if ( !fs::exists(dstpath) ) {
         fs::create_symlink(fs::read_symlink(srcPath),dstpath);
        }
}
```

But, i want to know the file to which  hard link is pointing to  again preserve it while copying it to new directory by calling `create_hardlink`.

Comment: _all_ files are hardlinks! Related: [What is the difference between a hard link and a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/346425/564341)

Comment: _"i want to know the file to which hard link is pointing to"_ - Do you mean that you'd like to lookup all the directory entries in the filesystem that are linked to the same content? There's nothing in C++ to do that and most filesystems do not provide a way to do that either.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes, I want to do something similar to ( added  the code for symlink check and preserve) what I have done for symbolic links.

Comment: If you have a path to a file and you see that it's got X hard links, there is no automatic way to figure out where those files are in the filesystem. You can search through the whole filesystem and look for files with the same inode, but that can take a lot of time.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I agree.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TedLyngmo on Windows, you can query the hard links that refer to a given target file by using `NTQueryInformationFile()` with the `FileHardLinkInformation` information class on the target file.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's nice! Too bad most filesystems don't have a similar feature.

Comment: Are you trying to implement something like `rsync --hard-links`? If so, you can look at rsync's source code and see what it does.